# Change background color based on value JS

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the background color of `<tr>` based on the value from a custom field.

(It will be in hex code --> `<td class="customfield_13209"> #FF0000 </td>`)

Code sample below.

How can I do this?

```
<tr id="issuerow322848" rel="322848" data-issuekey="CA-17059" class="issuerow">
<td class="issuekey">
    <a class="hidden-link issue-link" data-issue-key="CA-17059" href="/jira/browse/CA-17059" tabindex="-1" title="CA-17059"></a>

    <a class="issue-link" data-issue-key="CA-17059" href="/jira/browse/CA-17059">CA-17059</a>
</td>
<td class="summary">
    <p>
        <a class="issue-link parentIssue" data-issue-key="CA-17055" href="/jira/browse/CA-17055" title="Title of issue">CA-17055</a>
        <a class="issue-link" data-issue-key="CA-17059" href="/jira/browse/CA-17059">Jon Smith</a>
    </p>
</td>
<td class="assignee"> <span class="tinylink">        <a class="user-hover" rel="jsmith" id="assignee_jsmith" href="/jira/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=rprowadzisz">Jon Smith </a></span>
</td>
<td class="status">
    <span class=" span class not important" data-tooltip="<span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-title&quot;>Backlog</span>" title="" original-title="">Backlog</span>
</td>
<td class="updated"> <span title="2016-05-19 11:24 AM"><time datetime="2016-05-19T11:24:53+0200">2016-05-19</time></span> </td>
<td class="aggregatetimeestimate"></td>
<td class="customfield_13209"> #FF0000
</td>
<td class="issue_actions">
    <div class="action-dropdown aui-dd-parent">
        <a class="aui-dropdown-trigger aui-dd-link icon-tools-small issue-actions-trigger trigger-happy" id="actions_322848" title="Actions (Type . to access issue actions)" href="herif">
            <span>
            <em>Actions</em>
        </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Which element's background color do you want to change?

Comment: You said what you want, but you forgot to explain what problem you faced when doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to change the background color of the cell containing the hex color. You should be able to modify this to obtain the outcome you desire.

```
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName('customfield_13209');
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].style['background-color'] = cells[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neildcruz19/hkx4zbLs/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.customfield_13209').val() == "your desire"){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    }
});
```

It's jQuery, but if it will help you for solving your problem, then I'm satisfied.